# resubmitted app to google play store and still rejected warning sign is there

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My game app was rejected due to the ad content and i made changes according to that and followed the steps provided by google play feedback email   (Sign in to your Play Console, select Store presence > Store listing and click Resubmit app.) after clicking resubmit app there was a pop up" application has been saved" and  But I still have the warning flags within the dashboard saying "App rejected". what to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dashboard will still say "App rejected" until Google's team review your changes.

It should also say "processing update" near the "?", after your changes.

So wait some days (they says that normally are needed 7 days, but in same cases more).